# Component not rendering when the data in the state is changed React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a ListView with specific data. I need to update the style of one item in a list view when another action has happened. I am storing the change in the state. But the component is not being rendered.

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    sectionlistData: Data["SearchList"],
    headers: this.GetHeaders(Data["SearchList"]),
    current: 'A'
};
}

someAction(){
   this.setState({
     current: info.viewableItems[0].section.title+""
    })
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={{ marginTop : (Platform.OS) == 'ios' ? 20 : 25 }}>
    // some code   
    <View style={styles.contentListView}>
    <FlatList
        style={styles.alphabeticView}
        data={this.state.headers}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={this.state.current===item.key ? 
            styles.alphabetsHighlight : styles.alphabets} onPress= 
            {this.GetListItem.bind(this, item)} >{item.key}</Text>}
    />
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
alphabets:{
 textAlign: 'right',
 paddingRight: 10,
 height: 15,
 color: '#005B9A',
 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
},
alphabetsHighlight:{
 textAlign: 'right',
 paddingRight: 10,
 height: 15,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 color: '#005B9A',
 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
}
});
```

Here in the code, I am toggling the styles using the state, but When I update the state it is not re-rendering. Am I going doing the correct way? Does the react renders the component when the state data is used in CSS class? How can I achieve using the method I am following. If this does not help me how can I achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatList is a pure component. It will re-render based on the content of what is passed to `extraData`. So, although your state is changing, the FlatList's `extraData` should change! I think, you can just pass to `extraData`, `this.state` and things will update just fine.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I have gone through the documentation but I forgot the things about FlatList.